# Como se dibuja un 8 con asteriscos en C?

Tags: c, dev-c++, arte-ascii

Llevo días queriendo hacer ese código para dibujar un 8 en C con asteriscos, todo ha sido erroneo, como sería?

yo hice este, pero creo que está mal me da otra cosa que un 8, que tengo que cambiar para que en vez de un triángulo de 8?

```html
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int lineas;
    printf("ingresa la cantidad de líneas para el triangulo:");
    scanf("%d",&lineas);
    
    int i;
    
    for (i=1;i<=lineas;i++)
    
    {
        int j;
        for(j=1;j<=lineas-i;j++)
        
          printf("")
          
        for (j=1;j<=2*i-1:j++)
        
          printf("*")
          
         printf("\n");
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: bueno pero como es el codigo?

Comment: Por favor, intenta añadir el código o parte de lo que has hecho hasta el momento, para que la gente vea lo que has hecho y pueda orientarte o proponerte una solución. Actualmente no se puede saber cómo quieres ese 8, que tamaño, si tiene que ser inclinado... Como te dice @BetaM revisa el enlace de como preguntar.

Comment: Bien he hecho pero lo eliminé porque estaba mal, pero si tengo el tamaño del 8

Comment: sabes como hacer ese 8?

Comment: Amigo estuve mas de 5 dias intentando esto, me falta esa solamente, te pago si queres por transferencia bancaria o lo que sea, pero ayudenme, es un 8 impreso con asteriscos en lenguaje C

Comment: Muchacho pon lo que sea que tengas aki, aunque este mal, aunque sea un disparate pero ponlo

Comment: Ahi esta creo, ahora no se como hacer la forma ni nada

Comment: Aclararme una cosa, sabes hacer funciones y que requisitos debe tener tu codigo

Comment: amigo no se nada realmente, solo quiero saber como  es el codigo para imprimir un 8

Comment: Dame unos minutos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Imprimir(int azt1, int espacio, int azt2)
{
   for(int i = 1; i <= azt1; i++)
   {
      printf("*");
   }

   for(int i = 1; i <= espacio; i++)
   {
      printf(" ");
   }

   for(int i = 1; i <= azt2; i++)
   {
      printf("*");
   }

   printf('\n');
}
```

Lo que se hace aquí es crear una función que tiene tres parámetros enteros, el primer parámetro es la cantidad inicial de asteriscos, el segundo la cantidad de espacios, y el tercero la cantidad final de asteriscos.

Primero se hace un **ciclo for** desde **1** hasta el valor almacenado en la **variable azt1** que irá imprimiendo asteriscos.

Después se hará otro **ciclo for** desde **1** hasta el valor almacenado en la **variable espacio** que irá imprimiendo precisamente espacios.

Después se hace otro ciclo for desde **1** hasta el valor almacenado en la **variable azt2** que irá imprimiendo asteriscos. Y posteriormente se imprime un salto de línea **'\n'**.

Ahora bien para llamar esta función dentro del **metódo main** debes poner por ejemplo, si quisiéramos imprimir la primera línea del **8** que es todo asteriscos sería:

```
Imprimir(12, 0, 0);
```

Imprimiría los **12** asteriscos de la primera línea del **8**:

```
"************"
```

Para la tercera línea sería:

```
Imprimir(3, 6, 3);
```

Imprimiría **3** asteriscos, **6** espacios y después los **3** últimos asteriscos:

```
"***      ***"
```

Quedaría así en el **metódo main**:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
{
   Imprimir(12, 0, 0);
   Imprimir(12, 0, 0);
   Imprimir(3, 6, 3);
   Imprimir(3, 6, 3);
}

Imprimir(12, 0, 0);
Imprimir(12, 0, 0);
```

Comment: **#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
void{ Imprimir(int azt1, int espacio, int azt2)
{
   for(int i = 1; i<= azt1; i++)
   {
      printf("*");
   }

   for(int i = 1; i<=espacio;i++)
   {
      printf(" ");
   }

   for(int i = 1; i<=azt2; i++)
   {
      printf("*");
   }

   printf('\n');
}**         ( no se mandar codigo, pero algo asi seria? )

Comment: A ver la función que te puse debes desarrollarla en otro archivo, y entonces en el archivo del main harías un include al archivo donde pusiste tu función, algo así como #include <MiArchivo.h>

Comment: Como una alternativa a mi comentario anterior, en el mismo archivo del método main, copia la función que te puse arriba del método main y la llamaría dentro del método main algo así como void Imprimir(...){codigo} y después vendría el main como esta , y desde aquí usarías la función imprimir como te expliqué en mi respuesta

Comment: Mmmmm lo intenté pero no me funcionó, no tienes discord o whatsapp?

Comment: A ver coge la función void Imprimir() que te puse y copiala antes del método main

Comment: Si sigues teniendo dudas entra al chat de stackoverflow y busca la  sala japv y ahí podemos conversar

Comment: eso no se como hacerlo, ya que soy nuevo en esta página

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115741/discussion-between-japv-and-benjamin-veras).